# Export as OBJ and create fitting image texture

Tags: uv, export

I am very new to Blender and wanted to create a 3D chess board with figures for my render engine. I have designed the board and created a material and I can succesful export it as obj and load it up in my render engine. The problem I have is that when i want to bake the material as texture it looks distorted and has much empty space for a uv texture map. Also the uv coordinates in the obj file are no longer accurate and don't apply to the image.
This is what the image look like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0fL6.jpg
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like your UV Map is stretching. Select the face you want to uv-unwrap, view it from that in orthographic mode and in uv context menu, select project from view.